# How to authorize Facebook App for basic permissions without showing Authorization Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization

From the documentation it seems that the user should always authorize the Facebook application even to access basic permissions.

However, sites like Rotten Tomatoes and Clicker.com auto-authorize the logged facebook user without showing the authorization dialog. If you visit one of those sites for the first time they will be able to access your public data without you authorizing it. If I go to the Apps on my facebook settings, an entry will appear showing that I gave access to those applications (but I DID NOT).

How can this be possible? Is it related to the "Instant Personalization" feature for selected partners?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried and a dialog popped up. Did you try removing the permission (from your config in Facebook) and then logging-in in those sites again?

Comment: Let me clarify that. It only happens the first time. Just create a new facebook account for testing and go to rotten tomatoes or to clicker.com and you will see that the app will be automatically authorized. Later, if you go to the settings of your facebook account and remove the authorization, rotten tomatoes will show you the authorization dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was doing some research and yes, it's all about Instant Personalization.

From Facebook:

> We've partnered with a few websites to provide you with great,
>   personalized experiences the moment you arrive, such as immediately
>   playing the music you like or displaying friends' reviews. To tailor
>   your experience, **these partners** only **access public information** (like
>   your name and profile picture) and other information you've made
>   public.

From one of its partners:
[Clicker.com](http://www.clicker.com/popup/fbWhyConnect/)

So -at the time I'm writing this- unless you're a partner of Facebook, you'll have to show the old OAuth dialog.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. So dumb I didn't check that I could turn off the "Instant personalization". Using another facebook account I turned off the "Instant personalization" (following the instructions at http://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/"). Then if I go to clicker.com or rotten tomatoes, they no longer are able to fetch my basic information.